# How can I drive my EU-registered car from EU to the UK for a short period of time as a resident on both sides

Tags: eu, residency, car, driving

I am a resident in the EU and about to go to the UK for work. My work allows remote-working so I will spend around half time in the UK and half time in the EU. But anyway I assume I qualify as a resident in the UK. I will now be using the car in the UK for more than 6 months in a year, just once in a while, I'd like to travel by car between UK and EU. Can I do that?

My girlfriend is a resident only in the EU, and will be traveling with me. Would it be easier to do it by first transferring the car to her (non-UK resident)?
If the car is under her name, can I drive the car without her sitting beside me?

Comment: What’s the basis for your assumption that you’ll qualify as resident in the UK? You will normally be treated as UK resident in any tax year if you’re physically present in the UK for 183 days or more in that year. Some other ways in which you might be automatically treated as UK resident, include if you have your only home in the UK and spend 91 consecutive days there (including 30 days in the tax year), whilst having no overseas home in which you spend a certain amount of time during the tax year; if you work full time in the UK over the course of the year, without significant breaks.

Comment: How can I or the government decide before a year ends how many days I will spend in the UK? So technically I don't if I qualify at the moment I want to drive my car to the UK. Another question is that if I start in August, then only 5 months left for this calendar year. How should I count days?

Comment: You need to work out your residence status in the tax year, which starts 6 April https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income/residence Which UK work visa do you have? Have you looked at the rules on temporary vehicle imports https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk/temporary-imports? If the car is in your girlfriend’s name you can drive it in the UK, the same rules apply and you’ll need the right driving licence and insurance plus a letter of authorisation from your girlfriend to show to the police in case you’re ever stopped eg for speeding

Comment: Thank you for the links, really helpful. It seems a resident's status depends on many things according to all the questions I've answered. However, I am still confused because I need to decide now if I am a resident to know if I can temporarily import the vehicle. But to know that, I need to fill in how many days I am in the UK in the tax year, which I don't yet.

Comment: To add a bit of background, I am still in the EU and about to start a full-time job in the UK under a skilled worker visa (4 years). This job allows working from home so I might travel between UK and EU, working from both places. I don't have any records working in the UK before and don't know how many days I will stay in the UK in this current tax year, so how do I know if I am qualified as a resident at the moment of arriving in the UK?

Comment: @Z Gu Where do you consider ‘home’? If you consider your EU residence to be your main home, then just make sure you spend less than the max number of days allowed under the tax residency rules in the UK. Almost half of the tax year has passed already, so that shouldn’t be difficult for the first year at least

Comment: @Traveller, thank you for the detailed information.